# Is there any way Beeware is able to to display a picture on android phone?

Tags: android, image, webview, imageview, beeware

I build a Beeware app, and would lke to find a way to display a `.png` picture on my android phone from the phone storage. I understand that the `Toga` GUI in `Beeware` does not support neither `ImageView` nor `WebView` on `android`, and I could not find any `third party module` compatible with `Beeware`. Is there any workaround to this? Any suggestion of hint would be much appreciated.I attach below the relevant code that worked in windows but not in android, and the exception that caused the crash

**UPDATE:** I corrected following the answer by `mhsmith` below, and it WORKS GREAT! Many thanks. I updated the code below to reflect the correct script

```
import toga
from toga import App, Box, MainWindow
from toga import ImageView, Image
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW, BOTTOM, TOP, LEFT

with open('/storage/emulated/0/documents/my_picture.bmp',"rb") as f:
    image_data = f.read()
image_bytes = bytes(image_data)


class HelloWorld(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))

        self.myImage = toga.images.Image(data=image_bytes)
        self.img=toga.ImageView(image=self.myImage)
        main_box.add(self.img)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

def main():
    return HelloWorld()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/widgets_by_platform.html), ImageView and WebView on Android have a white dot, which means they are supported, though there may be some bugs in the current version.

In this case, your error is caused by the type of the `image` argument. Future versions of Toga will accept a string here, but the current stable version requires an [`Image`](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/api/resources/images.html) object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Looking at the Toga reference attached, I see that both ImageView and WebView have "white dot" for android, which i understand means that they are not supported. Also I exstensively tried both without success. For instance, ImageView worked well for me on Windows, but not on android. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I am out of ideas...

Comment: I attach in the UPDATE above the relevant code that worked in windows but not in android, and the exception that caused the crash

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: WORKS GREAT!!! many thanks